# jQuery, ajax, php, msyql: auto-suggest form input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a mysql db table that has every U.S. city, state, zip, lat, long. On my site page I have a form input for cities. As the user types, I'd like to suggest city, state. What current practices/techniques are good? (Limitations are jQuery, PHP, MYSQL)

**[Solution](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI has a nice autocomplete feature.

[JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

It is quite well configurable. You should send the data in JSON format from the server, Autocomplete will mostly handle the rest. Check out the docs.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try a pre-existing plugin such as:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Looks like it uses ajax and JSON to get data from your server. All styling is done in CSS too :o)